# Compare two URI/URL endpoints without parameter values

Tags: c#, string, url, uri

Let's say I have these two URIs:

1. `var uri1 = "/rest/api/projects/{projectName}/statuses"`
2. `var uri2 = "/rest/api/projects/XXX/statuses"`

As shown, they are different **only** in parameter definition and actual value.
However, I want to skip the parameter name/value check when comparing them.

As a result, comparing these two URIs should return true:

```cs
string.Equals(uri1, uri2) == true
```

Comment: Note tag [api] description: "Do Not use this tag"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some non-productive research, I came up with the following logic.

### Solution

```cs
public static class UrlExtensions
{
    public static bool CompareUrlsExceptParameters(this string urlToCompareFrom, string urlToCompareWith)
    {
        string pattern = @"\{[^/]*?\}"; // find out the {parameter} location in the main URL

        var match = Regex.Match(urlToCompareFrom, pattern);

        if (match.Success && match.Index < urlToCompareWith.Length) // found parameters in {}
        {
            var parameterName = match.Success ? match.Value : string.Empty;

            var index = match.Index;
            var replaceEndInd = urlToCompareWith.IndexOf('/', index);

            if (replaceEndInd == -1) // this might be the case when {parameter} found at the end of URL
            {
                replaceEndInd = urlToCompareWith.Length;
            }

            var parameterValue = urlToCompareWith.Substring(index, replaceEndInd - index);

            var resultUrl = urlToCompareFrom.Replace(parameterName, parameterValue);

            if (Regex.Match(resultUrl, pattern).Success) // contains more parameter(s)
            {
                return CompareUrlsExceptParameters(resultUrl, urlToCompareWith);
            }

            var isEqual = string.Equals(resultUrl, urlToCompareWith, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); // compare the strings ignoring case

            return isEqual;
        }

        return urlToCompareFrom.Contains(urlToCompareWith); // nothing found use ordinary comparison
    }
}
```

---

### Usage/Test

```cs
Assert.True("https://rest/api/projects/{projectName}".CompareUrlsExceptParameters("https://rest/api/projects/XXX"));
Assert.True("rest/api/projects/{projectName}/statuses".CompareUrlsExceptParameters("rest/api/projects/XXX/statuses"));
Assert.True("rest/api/projects/{projectName}/statuses/{statusId}".CompareUrlsExceptParameters("rest/api/projects/XXX/statuses/1"));
Assert.True("https://rest/api/projects/XXX".CompareUrlsExceptParameters("https://rest/api/projects/XXX"));

Assert.False("rest/api/projects/{projectName}/statuses/{statusId}/other".CompareUrlsExceptParameters("rest/api/projects/XXX/statuses/1"));
Assert.False("rest/api/projects/{projectName}/statuses/{statusId}".CompareUrlsExceptParameters("rest/api/projects/XXX/statuses/1/other"));
Assert.False("rest/api/projects/{projectName}/resources".CompareUrlsExceptParameters("rest/api/projects/XXX/statuses/1/other"));
Assert.False("rest/api/projects/{projectName}/resources".CompareUrlsExceptParameters("rest/api/statuses"));
Assert.False("rest/api/project/resources".CompareUrlsExceptParameters("rest/api/project/statuses"));
```